# Как очистить tk.Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Я видел способ `entry.delete(0, 'end')` но мне почему то постоянно пишет `_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "1"` и не важно что я туда напишу. Любой другой индекс или к примеру `'first'` он всегда выдаёт эту ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст ошибки

> bad **text** index "1"

говорит о том, что у вас не `Entry` а `Text` (для `Entry` аналогичная ошибка звучит как `bad entry index "1.0"`).

Для `Text` индексы должны быть формата `номер_строки.номер_колонки` (причем номер строки считается с 1, а номер колонки с 0) - в виде числа с плавающей точкой, например `1.0` (но не целого числа 1), или в виде строки `"1.0"`.

Рабочий пример:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry()
entry.pack()


def clear_entry():
    entry.delete(0, END)  # Удалить все, начиная с 0-го символа до конца


Button(text="Clear Entry", command=clear_entry).pack()


text = Text()
text.pack()


def clear_text():
    text.delete(1.0, END)  # Удалить все, начиная с 0-го символа 1-й строки до конца


Button(text="Clear Text", command=clear_text).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: извиняюсь за такую глупую ошибку, не уследил